# *** Security Sandbox Violation *** while using File.ApplicationStorageDirectory

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have an App that uses File.ApplicationStorageDirectory to store some files. Everything works as intended except the program throws this to the console after adding a file to the program:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'file:///%APPDATA%/actual/path/to/file.jpg' tried to access incompatible context 'app:/myApp.swf
```

I have read up on the violation error for example here [Accessing local and remote resources in a locally running SWF](http://probertson.com/articles/2006/10/06/local-remote-resources-local-swf/). But shouldn't File.ApplicationStorageDirectory be treated as local too even if it's on a roaming profile? We use ApplicationStorageDirectory on other projects too with no errors.

The File adder uses just regular DragDrop-handling via FileBrowser-component to List-based container. It only puts the warning while doing in-app drag drops. If I drop a file from any Windows Explorer (via NativeDragManager) or with File.browseForOpen-method no Violation occurs.

It only gets triggered drag & dropping within app to within app. And like I said, other than the warning, it works as expected. Any ideas?